# Mixing AND and OR in a WHERE clause has unexpected results

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
WHERE operation = 'cmn'
  AND client = '' OR client IS NULL
  AND ts >= '2014-03-01'
  AND ts <'2014-09-01'
```

I am trying this `where` condition, however the OR is not working as expected.

My idea is keep the cmn obligatory but the client could be empty or null.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap the `or` in brackets:

```
WHERE operation = 'cmn'
AND (client = '' OR client IS NULL)
AND ts >= '2014-03-01'
AND ts < '2014-09-01'
```

Comment: By way of explanation: `OR` has lower precedence than `AND`, so `a AND b OR c AND d` is interpreted as `(a AND b) OR (c AND d)`. If you want `a AND (b OR c) AND d` you must say so explicitly.